# JSON with question "title" in answers JSON format

Tags: php, json, webhooks

I need assistance taking the below JSON, and converting it to a better formatted JSON, or at least a format the webhook I am using will accept. When I send this data to a different site via webhook. I don't need all of it, but the most important is the 'answers' section. Not all answers are just straight text, some are multiple-choice, etc... But I mainly just need to have JSON code, which will be something like:

```
 {
    "type": "choice",
    "choice": {
      "label": "Barcelona"
    },
    "field": {
      "id": "mNgn3likMf3O",
      "type": "multiple_choice",
      "ref": "01F3ZGM0W3745KR2FW1CP8Q5S4",
      "title": "Please select the pillars of a SASE-ready architecture that your organization has adopted and implemented."
    }
  },
```

But needs to be in JSON format. I will need to have other data as well, such as phone number, email, etc. but the answer is the part I am not sure how to handle. I am using a middle piece that will be in PHP taking this data and converting it to a JSON format.

Detail would be in the answer piece you see a "ref", which references the question block in the top part of the code. Could you help with getting the answer section to have the "ref" call the matching "ref" from the top part, which would be the question directly, and have the "title" show in the answer as well? That would allow us to have the proper format the webhook would accept and we can target as needed. Does that help?

```
{
  "event_id": "01GW5AQQGETNY8SRM4MZHY1892",
  "event_type": "form_response",
  "form_response": {
    "form_id": "B05nYbDj",
    "token": "01GW5AQQGETNY8SRM4MZHY1892",
    "landed_at": "2023-03-22T18:54:08Z",
    "submitted_at": "2023-03-22T18:54:08Z",
    "definition": {
      "id": "B05nYbDj",
      "title": "Cisco SASE Survey for Burwood Group (copy)",
      "fields": [
        {
          "id": "mNgn3likMf3O",
          "ref": "01F3ZGM0W3745KR2FW1CP8Q5S4",
          "type": "multiple_choice",
          "title": "Please select the pillars of a SASE-ready architecture that your organization has adopted and implemented.",
          "properties": {}
        },
        {
          "id": "c5z21uSbVsHn",
          "ref": "833343d3-4840-4cb2-841f-37afdfbc3a89",
          "type": "opinion_scale",
          "title": "How would you *rate your company's overall SASE-ness*?",
          "properties": {}
        },
        {
          "id": "eUR85WQGMJmv",
          "ref": "e0d9b18c-45ce-4d24-ae51-35fa44c8c577",
          "type": "multiple_choice",
          "title": "Which of these *network solutions* are you currently employing in your organization?",
          "properties": {}
        },
        {
          "id": "SEHdZOtBuMPH",
          "ref": "80808a56-8eff-40fe-8267-cdbd8b5b2143",
          "type": "multiple_choice",
          "title": "Which of these *cloud security solutions* are you currently employing in your organization?",
          "properties": {}
        },
        {
          "id": "JyTK17cLO22J",
          "ref": "67427da4-b210-4253-adde-36dd524e91f8",
          "type": "multiple_choice",
          "title": "At your company, how often are *perimeter/edge security controls and monitoring capabilities* included in your network engineering and design?",
          "properties": {}
        },
        {
          "id": "Ndry3UZqKz9j",
          "ref": "968531e4-98fb-46f4-9694-dca9fc41d9fd",
          "type": "multiple_choice",
          "title": "Does your organization adopt a *zero-trust posture* when determining access to company resources?",
          "properties": {}
        },
        {
          "id": "9wS9mei2XxA4",
          "ref": "939b6dca-742c-4036-a48b-a9221b03cb28",
          "type": "multiple_choice",
          "title": "What *solutions/vendors* is your company leveraging to implement a *zero-trust approach*?",
          "properties": {}
        },
        {
          "id": "zpQHU05AiOHg",
          "ref": "2155696f-6c00-4953-b128-c8af2e090c7b",
          "type": "long_text",
          "title": "What are the top 3 *limitations and/or challenges *to achieve SASE success for your company?",
          "properties": {}
        },
        {
          "id": "HTFv9Xi8ffhL",
          "ref": "ac6ca834-9648-4a5a-91a5-42b39e4281ca",
          "type": "multiple_choice",
          "title": "Which *internal team in your organization* is primarily responsible for your *SASE strategy*?",
          "properties": {}
        },
        {
          "id": "u8J4DhCofU8e",
          "ref": "66395568-1533-437f-abe8-7a1b8c834b64",
          "type": "short_text",
          "title": "What is your *full name*?",
          "properties": {}
        },
        {
          "id": "HCDcgXhRPJcs",
          "ref": "c929257d-099a-4cd3-876b-1c1cdede1eb7",
          "type": "short_text",
          "title": "What is your *role and/or job title*?",
          "properties": {}
        },
        {
          "id": "Ua8uGbaVxtmt",
          "ref": "386728a9-c4d7-43d5-af2e-1cb822a1f5ce",
          "type": "short_text",
          "title": "What is the *name of your company or organization*?",
          "properties": {}
        },
        {
          "id": "Lt3LXb90adwu",
          "ref": "9913e0e9-bbe3-4696-961e-c377cf932edd",
          "type": "short_text",
          "title": "Where is* your company or organization located*?",
          "properties": {}
        },
        {
          "id": "nDL4kTJXeHjL",
          "ref": "cabf2dfc-319b-4066-a56f-cee5b0eaedcc",
          "type": "email",
          "title": "Please provide us your *business* *email address*.",
          "properties": {}
        },
        {
          "id": "0cPtqsbaL5ZD",
          "ref": "04360852-006a-48aa-a809-346a2c1109b6",
          "type": "phone_number",
          "title": "Finally, please provide us your *direct phone number* so we can verify your responses and information if required.",
          "properties": {}
        }
      ]
    },
    "answers": [
      {
        "type": "choice",
        "choice": {
          "label": "Barcelona"
        },
        "field": {
          "id": "mNgn3likMf3O",
          "type": "multiple_choice",
          "ref": "01F3ZGM0W3745KR2FW1CP8Q5S4"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "number",
        "number": 42,
        "field": {
          "id": "c5z21uSbVsHn",
          "type": "opinion_scale",
          "ref": "833343d3-4840-4cb2-841f-37afdfbc3a89"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "choice",
        "choice": {
          "label": "Barcelona"
        },
        "field": {
          "id": "eUR85WQGMJmv",
          "type": "multiple_choice",
          "ref": "e0d9b18c-45ce-4d24-ae51-35fa44c8c577"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "choice",
        "choice": {
          "label": "Barcelona"
        },
        "field": {
          "id": "SEHdZOtBuMPH",
          "type": "multiple_choice",
          "ref": "80808a56-8eff-40fe-8267-cdbd8b5b2143"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "choice",
        "choice": {
          "label": "Barcelona"
        },
        "field": {
          "id": "JyTK17cLO22J",
          "type": "multiple_choice",
          "ref": "67427da4-b210-4253-adde-36dd524e91f8"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "choice",
        "choice": {
          "label": "Barcelona"
        },
        "field": {
          "id": "Ndry3UZqKz9j",
          "type": "multiple_choice",
          "ref": "968531e4-98fb-46f4-9694-dca9fc41d9fd"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "choice",
        "choice": {
          "label": "Barcelona"
        },
        "field": {
          "id": "9wS9mei2XxA4",
          "type": "multiple_choice",
          "ref": "939b6dca-742c-4036-a48b-a9221b03cb28"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
        "field": {
          "id": "zpQHU05AiOHg",
          "type": "long_text",
          "ref": "2155696f-6c00-4953-b128-c8af2e090c7b"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "choice",
        "choice": {
          "label": "Barcelona"
        },
        "field": {
          "id": "HTFv9Xi8ffhL",
          "type": "multiple_choice",
          "ref": "ac6ca834-9648-4a5a-91a5-42b39e4281ca"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
        "field": {
          "id": "u8J4DhCofU8e",
          "type": "short_text",
          "ref": "66395568-1533-437f-abe8-7a1b8c834b64"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
        "field": {
          "id": "HCDcgXhRPJcs",
          "type": "short_text",
          "ref": "c929257d-099a-4cd3-876b-1c1cdede1eb7"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
        "field": {
          "id": "Ua8uGbaVxtmt",
          "type": "short_text",
          "ref": "386728a9-c4d7-43d5-af2e-1cb822a1f5ce"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
        "field": {
          "id": "Lt3LXb90adwu",
          "type": "short_text",
          "ref": "9913e0e9-bbe3-4696-961e-c377cf932edd"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "email",
        "email": "an_account@example.com",
        "field": {
          "id": "nDL4kTJXeHjL",
          "type": "email",
          "ref": "cabf2dfc-319b-4066-a56f-cee5b0eaedcc"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "phone_number",
        "phone_number": "+34123456789",
        "field": {
          "id": "0cPtqsbaL5ZD",
          "type": "phone_number",
          "ref": "04360852-006a-48aa-a809-346a2c1109b6"
        }
      }
    ],
    "ending": {
      "ref": "default_tys"
    }
  }
```

Comment: We, or at least me, were not able to fully understand your issue. To make things clearer, I suggest you provide a data simple of the desired output.

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work? Show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Adapted the solution with the new informations provided**

Let me see if i have understood.

Try this:

```
<?php

$data = json_decode (/* here the json string received */, true);

$defs = &$data['form_response']['definition']['fields'];
$answs = &$data['form_response']['answers'];

$defsRefs = array_column($defs, 'ref');

$arrResult = [];

foreach ($answs as $k => $a)
{
    if (($key = array_search($a['field']['ref'], $defsRefs)) !== false)
    {
        $a['field']['title'] = $defs[$key]['title'];
        
        $a['field']['answer'] = $a[$a['type']];
        
        // or substitute the previous line with these if better
        //$answer = (array)$a[$a['type']];
        //$a['field']['answer'] = reset($answer);
        
        $arrResult['question_' . $k + 1] = $a['field'];
    }

}

$result = json_encode($arrResult /*, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT*/);
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be close to what I need, I will see more as I see the results. It's currently not showing anything. I have even turned on error reporting, and no errors show. @pippo

Comment: Try ```var_dump ($data)```: perhaps the initial JSON string is not well-formed.
You can also try an online JSON validator to see if it's all ok

Comment: NOTE: the example you posted is missing a closing parenthesis

Comment: I added to the end, and seemed to kick out data `echo json_encode($arrResult, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

This is close, what would be nice is if I can have it in format


`question_1: {
      id: "mNgn3likMf3O",
      type: "multiple_choice",
      ref: "01F3ZGM0W3745KR2FW1CP8Q5S4",
      title: "Please select the pillars of a SASE-ready architecture that your organization has adopted and implemented."
      answer: "Barcelona"  
    }`

Comment: you can see example of it so far: [link](https://www.hostusa.us/tsl/typeform/api_back.php)

Comment: It wouldn’t let me tag you in comments above @pippo

Comment: I've adapted the solution with the new informations provided  - I'm not sure I understand the sentence about *choice/label* so i've provided 2 alternatives

Comment: Awesome, almost there, for the choice options, it's under the "label". Is there a way we can for the type "multiple_choice" can have the label removed and just have it answer: {"Barcelona"} similar to "opinion_scale", and "short_text" @pippo

Comment: @Anthony Have you tried replacing  the line ```$a['field']['answer'] = $a[$a['type']];``` with the commented ones?

Comment: YES! thank you, one more thing, since this will be taking json code for multiple forms for a webhook, at the end, I need the updated json to be sent via web hook in my code to send that data. @pippo

Comment: @Antony that is a more complex task and must provided more deatils on it, so i suggest you to open a new topic explaining the needings with all details about *webhook* and i will appreciate if you set my answer as 'accepted'

Comment: Okay, I think I was able to get the webhook piece fixed. Is there a way I can custom some of the types, so for type email, I do not want "question_", and can I also have "question_" along side with id, type, ref, ect... @pippo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252756/discussion-between-anthony-and-pippo).

Comment: are you still available?

Comment: yes... but maybe it's time to ask a new question

Comment: I have over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76870018/json-modified-to-label-as-answer